# What exact material are sun spots made from?

Tags: star, the-sun

Questions all relate to my theory and original question.

Approximate total mass of a sun spot ?

Exact chemical composition of a sun spot?

Answers please.

---

https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/pt.6.1.20210203a/full/

Here is supporting evidence that sun spots or material on the surface of the sun is infact si, silicon. Iron, Fe. And magnesium.

27% of earth is silicon. 30%iron and magnesium.

Please un delete my former question, could the planets be emerging from the sun, to give context to these follow up questions.

Comment: You might want to consider a change in your attitude and show some of your own effort in finding an answer and make this question a question which can stand on its own. People with wild ideas have the obligation to prove those right - not others to prove whatever fancy wrong. If you disagree: please disprove that I have a zoo of unicorns and ice age mamoth playing chess among eachother in a well-hidden place

Comment: I do have answers but seek other views on the subject. My research in to the formation of the solar sys is on the web page in g sites in previously deleted question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about amateur personal theories with no basis in mainstream physics are off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

There is no chemical difference between a sun spot and the rest of the Sun's "surface".

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311622636_New_laboratory_spectra_of_the_Fe_6_and_Fe_7_ions

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13999258_Water_on_the_Sun_Line_Assignments_Based_on_Variational_Calculations

Answer (score 4):

It's no different from a piece of hot steel being momentarily darkened by contact with a cold tool: the only difference between a sunspot and the rest of the visible sun is temperature. Most of the photosphere consists of convection cells with a temperature at the top of 5780 K. In sunspots, magnetic fields hinder convection and temperatures get as low as 3000 K. Since thermal emission varies with the fourth power of temperature, such a sunspot emits less than a tenth as much as its surroundings.

Answer (score 4):

Sunspots are not different in composition from the rest of the solar photosphere.

> They are regions of reduced surface temperature caused by concentrations of magnetic flux that inhibit convection.
> [Wikipedia: Sunspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot)

Convection is how energy is primarily transported to the photosphere; because the magnetic flux inhibits convection, sunspots get less energy from the sun's interior than other regions in the photosphere, and so can be more than 2,000K degrees cooler-- appearing dark in contrast to normal regions of the sun (although since the spots are still 3,000-4,000K, they still glow brightly in themselves).

> Isolated from the surrounding photosphere, a single sunspot would shine brighter than the full moon, with a crimson-orange color

Because sunspots are of widely varying size and are just regions of the photosphere, it's difficult to speak of 'mass' sensibly, but back-of-the-envelope a fairly large spot, with a surface area comparable to the earth, might involve 5 x 10^12 metric tons of gas cooler than the surrounding photosphere.